# Options for removing rear-window tint?

Tags: windshield, window, tint

The rear-window tint on my car has bubbled badly preventing visibility so I've been trying to remove it. So far I have had no success and am nearing my wits end. So far I have tried:

- Spraying the window with ammonia and blocking it off with black garbage bags to produce heat
- Steaming with a garment steamer
- Terpentine
- Vinegar
- Plastic scraper
- Windex
- Fine steel wool
- Scouring pad
- Various combinations of the above

So far the only thing that works is razor blades, but I can't use these as they also damage the demister lines.

I'm desperate here as I can't even register the car to take it to a tin t specialist, without first removing the tint. Are there any other options out ther?

Comment: Try using a hair dryer and some type of scraper to get it off.

Comment: Wow, you've covered all the bases. I would try to peel part of the window tint just enough to spray some paint thinner or aircraft paint remover behind the window to make the glue softer... maybe even let it soak on the film for a bit to soften it up

Comment: Use a heat gun to soften the glue, then peel off the tint, then you can use solvent to remove the glue.

Comment: @Moab I was about to suggest a heat gun, but wouldn't that crack the window if the glass got to hot

Comment: Nothing is aggie proof.

Comment: As long as the temperature in a single area isn't too much hotter than other areas, it should be fine. The problem is when one area is significantly hotter than an immediately adjacent area.

Answer (score 1):

A hair dryer is adequate, and a heat gun may get too hot for the window.

I removed tint on a station wagon, using the hair dryer trick, and at least for that tint, on that vehicle, it worked ok.  Three demister/defroster leads were damaged.  While that issue may be off-topic, it will come up.  In a darkened area (like a garage at night) you may be able to see the arcing of partially failed defroster traces, which helps tell you where to place conductive adhesive.

Heat guns tend to put out much higher temperatures and could heat on one spot cracking the glass.  Given that automotive glass gets daily heat insult, it may not be an issue, but a hair dryer generally has much lower  exit temperatures.

Mineral spirits may work on most adhesives.  In my case, there was very little residue.

Comment: I burned out a hair drier doing this - turns out they're usually not intended to be used for long periods of time. I recommend using a heat gun and just don't let it get too hot - which is easily controlled by holding it further away from the window than you would a hair drier.